# Why do I need to create a threadsafe version of self for some completion blocks and not others?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a view with a UIPageViewController and on the method to set view controllers I have use a thread safe instance of self like this:

```
__block typeof(self) threadedSelf = self;

[self.pageController setViewControllers:@[p]
                              direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse
                               animated:YES
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 if (finished) {
                                     [threadedSelf performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNavTitleText) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                                 }
                             }];
```

The completion block looks similar to other completion blocks, like the UIView animation method, but this is the first completion block where I've had to create a block version of self. Why is this method different than other completion callbacks? Is it because this is an instance method where the UIView animation is a class (static) method?

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need `threadedSelf` in the first place? You are making an initial assumption here; why? Is it because `setViewControllers` is being called on a background thread? If so, why are you doing _that_?

Comment: If I don't set it with a block I get a warning: "Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle". I'm sure I could do the same thing with __weak instead of __block but all the examples I've seen for this method on UIPageViewController specifically use __block.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with "threaded". It has to do with memory management. That's exactly what I'm asking. Is the question that you don't understand what a weak reference is - why you need one here, and how to get one?

Comment: ah gotcha. I got some of this from a tutorial where they listed the variable as "threadsafe" in their explanation. I guess that's not really the case. I know what a weak reference is, I wasn't sure about the __block reference though or why this reference has to be managed differently than other completion blocks.

Comment: Weak references are threadsafe if you do the weak-strong dance, which I point you to in my comment on my answer. The reason is that if `self` were to vanish out from under you, the weak-strong dance allows you to detect safely the resulting nil weak ref and go no further. I have never seen `__block` used in that way and it is not what Apple officially recommends in their WWDC videos; they do the weak-strong dance (and they even call it that; I believe they got that name from me, but I could be wrong, maybe it existed before I started using it :) m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a thread safety issue, it's a retain cycle issue.  Blocks retain the objects they use.  Evidently, from the warning, this block is being retained by `self`, so if it *also* uses/retains `self` then you have a retain cycle.

You should use the `__weak` qualifier on the pointer to self that you use in the block, like:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

Both `__weak` and `__block` are frequently used for variables that will appear in blocks, but they have different purposes.  The `__weak` qualifier prevents the block from retaining the object and is exactly the tool you need to prevent a retain cycle.  The `__block` qualifier does prevent the block from retaining the object, but its purpose is really to indicate that the object might be changed inside the block (i.e. changes made to the object inside the block must be visible outside of the block).  That is *not* the case in your example.  You refer to `self` but you are not modifying the pointer (`self = foo`).  Therefore you should use the `__weak` qualifier instead of the `__block` qualifier.

In many cases you need neither qualifier.  There will be a retain cycle only if the block is actually retained by an object referred to inside the block.  Frequently, you will use blocks that are not retained by any object you own, for example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    [self makeSomeChangesToBeAnimated];
}];
```

Here the animation block can safely refer to `self` with no qualifier, because the block is not retained by `self`.  It might be retained by something *else* but not by `self`, so you do not need to use the `__weak` qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

If `self` retains a block that refers to `self`, we have a retain cycle. The warning you are trying to avoid is telling you that that might happen here. I don't know whether it's true or not but, given the explicit warning, I take no chances: I pass a weak version of `self` into the block, using the "weak-strong dance".

Comment: For the structure of the weak-strong dance and further surrounding explanation about memory management and retain cycles, see my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#EXstrongWeakDance

Comment: So is this different than other completion blocks because it's an instance method calling the method on an instance of itself (which could go away before completion) where as something like the UIView animate completion handler is a class method which can't be released before completion?